# Merge array's consecutive items when equal

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Trying to create an array out of existing one where all the consecutive items are merged:

```js
[undefined, undefined, undefined] -> [undefined]

[undefined, 'item', undefined] -> [undefined, 'item', undefined]

[undefined, undefined, 'item'] -> [undefined, 'item']
```

I've tried `[...new Set(temp)]`, where temp is the one of the above but that does not keep indexes.

EDIT: It would be beneficial if I could know number of items being merged into one when applicable

Please note the 2nd case where, despite duplicated items, array stays untouched

Comment: It's not a duplicate as this is about duplicate _consecutive_ items.

Comment: @Zlatko: I've changed the dupe target.

Answer (score 2):

```
  array.filter((el, i, a) => !i || el !== a[i - 1])
```

Comment: Okay, this may work, but considering the single-letter variable names and the fact that the OP didn't think of this approach, could you explain what's going on here?